# Editing text in ActionBar on a template using Sketch3

Tags: android, ide, material-design, user-experience, sketch-3

I am trying to edit text on an ActionBar in a Sketch Android template I downloaded. However, when I make changes, I don't see the changes being reflected on the Sketch Artboard. I also installed an "unlock all layers" plugin, however, I am still facing the same issue.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: if you're trying to changr title on Action Bar, you can do it by opening your manifest file and then in activity you would see `title`. Please be more clear, maybe screenshots would be useful

Comment: I am new to sketch3. Is there a manifest file in sketch 3? I mainly want to come up with a mockup screen.

Comment: so you're doing it in Sketch Up not Android Studio/Eclipse right?

Comment: That is correct. I am using sketch 3.